In describing the multiplier process, is it right to
explain in terms of increase in national income --> increase in consumption and increase in savings?
If I assume mpc is 0.90 and initial govt injection is $1:
Injection of \$1 increases national income by \$1 --> households receive an increase in income of \$1 by working on project --> households increase consumption by \$0.90 and increase saving by \$0.10 --> producers of domestic goods receive an increase in income of \$0.90 and increase their consumption by \$0.81 and increase saving by \$0.09. Or should I not explain in terms of increase in the national income/consumption and saving?
